# To fetch the data that will get rendered when an html file is open in browser

Tags: python, html

"I have a .html file. I want to read the data to one of my variable and the data should be same like it gets rendered on the browser.I need only plain text. Please help me with python code snippet"

Comment: Your should share your code and the input with us.

Comment: I have the html file called "testhtml.html" that has below content.
The html file has data that will not be displayed in the browser because data is hidden using "<div style="height: 0px; overflow: hidden;">".
With below code I am able to fetch all text including hidden text. But i need text that actually gets displayed in the browser.
'
file = open("testhtml.html", "r")

import html2text
html = open("Receipt_Buffer.html").read()
print( html2text.html2text(html))
'

Comment: @milanbalazs, please help

Comment: I have posted an answer. I hope it can help you.

Comment: @milanbalazs, I am getting error: ValueError: unknown url type: 'testhtml.html'

Comment: Sorry for my late. I have edited my answer.

Comment: @milanbalazs, It should print only the "Display Block" but again it is printing all texts

Comment: You should share the output of script and the related part of HTML file which you want to parse. It's hard to provide a correct parser without all related details about your issue.

Comment: "<center><table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0" style="width: 100%;"><tr colspan="2" style="width: 100%;"><td nowrap align="left" style="width: 100%;"><div style="height: 0px; overflow: hidden;"><div ><div ><div ><p>Hidden Block</p></div></div></div></div><div ><div ><div ><div ><p>Display Block</p></div></div></div></div></td></tr></table></center><br/><br/><br/><br/><br style="page-break-after: always" />"      Put This in any .html file and open it in browser. What ever gets displayed on the browser is the data I need. Now I am getting like this "Hidden Block     Display Block"

Answer (score 0):

You can try the following script. I should print only the visible web page text from HTML.

**Code:**

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup


def tag_visible(element):
    if element == "Display Block":
        return True
    return False


def text_from_html(body):
    soup = BeautifulSoup(body, 'html.parser')
    texts = soup.findAll(text=True)
    visible_texts = filter(tag_visible, texts)
    return u" ".join(t.strip() for t in visible_texts)


with open("testhtml.html", "r") as open_html:
    html = open_html.read()
print(text_from_html(html))
```

**Input HTML file:**

```
<center>
    <table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0" style="width: 100%;">
        <tr colspan="2" style="width: 100%;">
            <td nowrap align="left" style="width: 100%;">
                <div style="height: 0px; overflow: hidden;">
                    <div>
                        <div>
                            <div>
                                <p>Hidden Block</p>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div>
                    <div>
                        <div>
                            <div>
                                <p>Display Block</p>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</center>
<br/>
<br/>
<br/>
<br/>
<br style="page-break-after: always" />
```

Output:

```
>>> python3 test.py 
Display Block
```